# Map a network drive from a Mac network on my PC

Tags: windows-7, macos, network-shares

**The Problem**

I'm experiencing a problem. I the lone windows (7) user on a Mac network. I need to connect to a shared drive using a specific username/password.

**What I do**

My understanding is I need to map a network drive, right?

So I open windows explorer, find the Computer and share under Network. I right click and say "Map Network Drive...". I tick "Connect using different credentials" and enter my details.

It thinks for a minute and says "The Network folder specified is currently mapped to a username and password. To connect using a different user name and password, first disconnect any existing mapping to this network share."

**The Twist**

The twist is I don't have any other mapped network drives. My Computer on shows my C drive...

So how do I connect with different credentials?

Comment: If you type `net use` in a command prompt, what does it show?

Comment: @slhck Status Local Remote Network
-----------------
OK                     \\THE-SERVER\SHARED-FOLDER1  Microsoft Windows Network
The command completed successfully. - The-Server is the same machine as I'm trying to connect to but Share-Folder1 isn't the same share...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are the folders in the Mac enabled to share using SMB and/or AFP?

Follow this easy tutorial and you should be fine

[Share files from Mac to Windows](http://osxdaily.com/2011/09/08/share-files-from-mac-to-windows-pc/)